# Динамическая высота при вылезании клавиатуры

Tags: android, клавиатура, разметка

Здравствуйте, каким образом возможно сделать так, чтобы все view при вылезании клавиатуры были так же хорошо показаны когда клавиатура задвинута?

Вот, очень некрасиво получается

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я понял, `windowSoftInputMode` действует на `EditText` а у меня перекрывается кнопка. Наверху еще будет картинка. В итоге нужно как-то поднимать `Layout` при вылезании клавиатуры, уменьшая все отступы. Но как это будет выглядеть на планшетах?

Вообщем, что можно предпринять?

Comment: А что именно в `windowSoftInputMode` вы использовали? `adjustPan|adjustResize`?

Comment: @McDaggen, да все подряд. Не нравятся мне эти поведения, я сейчас скоро закончу один хак, выложу ответ

Comment: @McDaggen, никак. Сдался. Очень, очень плохо, что нельзя перехватить поведение открытия клавиатуры

Comment: Человек пишет что метод работает, попробуйте реализовать у себя. https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/1063861

Comment: @McDaggen, ух ты, как же я не заметил это. Скоро отпишусь!

Comment: @McDaggen, почему то `diff` равна 0

Comment: Попробуйте сделать это в java коде, без хмл: `getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);`

Comment: @Соколов, это не то, у меня клавиатура не перекрывает текстовые поля, она перекрывает кнопку